# Send custom HTTP headers AND get response header - curl

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to curl (in PHP) a URL and send a custom header in the request. But then I also need to be able to view the response header that is returned. I'm querying an external API that I don't control.

I've tried using both the CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER and CURLOPT_HEADER options but they don't seem to work well together. CURLOPT_HEADER seems to overwrite the request headers so I can't authenticate my request BUT I then can view the headers in the response. If I take CURLOPT_HEADER out, I can successfully authenticate, but can't view headers.

**PHP Code:**

```
$url = "http://url-goes-here";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
$headers = array("X-Auth-Token: $token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$out = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php), it has to be

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); // or TRUE
```

instead of

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $headers);
```

**EDIT**: I must say I can't replicate the issue. I've created two scripts: a.php (using your content, with $url changed to 'http://localhost/b.php') and b.php (queried by a.php) which contains this:

```
<?php
foreach (getallheaders() as $name => $value) {
    echo "$name: $value\n";
}
```

So when I run `php a.php`, I get this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 16 Feb 2016 02:42:45 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Fedora) PHP/5.6.15
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.15
Content-Length: 50
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Host: localhost
Accept: */*
X-Auth-Token: xxx
```

Which means I'm 1) getting the response headers successfully, and 2) receiving them successfully as well from `a.php`. I'd suggest you trying something similar and see if your web server (or your application) is playing tricks with you.

Comment: Have you tried setting CURLOPT_HEADER *before* $headers is initialized and passed into curl? (A shot in the dark, but it's kind of hard to debug without seeing what your script and the remote endpoint send and receive.)

Comment: Tried that but also didn't work. What more would you like to know to help debug the issue? At the moment I get a 401 Unauthorised response header as the token is not being sent properly in the header.

Comment: Your edit looks more like you've programmed b.php to echo the headers into the body of the b.php file? I'm trying to view the headers directly that have been set, this is different to the body.

Comment: There are 2 sets of headers I get when I run `php a.php`: those I get from the server (listed before the new line break, i.e. those that I get by setting CURLOPT_HEADER to 1) and those that I receive from a.php inside b.php (i.e. those that I set via CURLOPT_HTTPHEADERS).